# linq validation issue

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have a database with a field value going from 1 to 10. When entering a value into this database the entries must be in order from 1 to 8, You can add 9 or 10 whenever you see fit. I had a Linq statement to grab the last value in the database that was less then 9 and test it against the value being entered. However it does not seem to be working when 10 is the last value in my database.

```
List<Row> list = new List<Row>();
list.AddRange(_db.Rows.ToList());

 // list = { "1", "2", "8","7","8","9","10" }
Row row = (
             from p in list
             where p.ProcessStage.CompareTo("9") < 0
             select p)
             .Last();
```

Im looking to return the last 8 value. Currently this statement is returning 10, and i have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

**Solution**

I should have been converting  to an int before checking.

```
 Row row = (
             from p in list
             where Convert.ToInt32(p.ProcessStage) < 9
             select p)
             .Last();
```

Comment: What is `entires` and what is `list`?

Comment: Ive edited the post about entries = list,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has something to do with [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Number 10 is greater than number 9, but **string** "10" is less than string "9".

I guess, table column has the wrong type.

Comment: or, if you can't change the type in your db, simply parse it to `int`